# Rails , cant view register user page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, postgresql

I keep getting this error when I try and view my register user page

> Firefox has detected that the server
>   is redirecting the request for this
>   address in a way that will never
>   complete.

```
def register
    #User registration form
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Account Created Successfully"
      redirect_to(:action=>'menu')
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Please fill in all fields"
      redirect_to(:action=>'register')
    end
  end


<div class="user new">
  <h2>Create User</h2>

  <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:action => 'register'}) do |f| %>

    <table summary="User form fields">
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:first_name) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:last_name) %></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>UserName</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:user_name) %></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>Password</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:password) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <tr>
        <th>Email</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:email) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <tr>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:telephone) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><%= submit_tag("Register") %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>


  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you putting a redirect in your view method?

```
redirect_to(:action=>'register')
```

Are you distinguishing between the view method and the method that is actually fired when the user submits the form? Ex. for RestfulAuthentication the view is called "new", and the actual method that creates a user after the form is submitted is called "create".

Answer (score 1):

You're redirecting you the same register action in the `else`.  Try `render :action => '<action that contains the form>'`

Comment: Also, the equals (`<%=`) is not needed in the `form_for`. Just do `<%`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that FireFox message means that you have some kind of server redirect loop going on. For example, if you have a before filter in your application controller that says if the user in not logged in then send them to the register user page. But then on redirect to the register page, that user is still not logged in. Then Rails will try to redirect them again to that page. Thus forming a loop.